# Deleting cross referenced data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
id            rid
-----       ------
1             2
2             1
2             3
3             2
1             3
3             1
```

I want to change this so only one row per relation exists.

e.g:

```
id           rid
-----       ------
1             2
2             3
1             3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always have pairs (as in your example):

```
delete from table
    where id > rid;
```

This keeps the record where `id` is smaller.

If there is the possibility that no all pairs exist, then:

```
delete t
    from table t left outer join
         (select least(id, rid) as lid, greatest(id, rid) as gid, count(*) as cnt
          from table t2
          group by least(id, rid), greatest(id, rid)
         ) t2
         on least(t.id, t.rid) = t2.lid and greatest(t.id, t.rid) = gid
    where id < rid or t2.cnt = 1;
```

EDIT (explanation):

How does the second query work?  Let me be honest, what I want to write is this:

```
delete t from table t
   where id < rid or
         (id > rid and
          not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.rid and t2.rid = t.id
         );
```

That is, I want to keep all records where `id < rid`.  But then, I also want to keep all singleton records where `rid > id`.  I don't think MySQL allows the syntax with the `where` clause.

Instead, the query in the answer counts the number of times that a pair exists, by looking at the smallest value and the largest value.  For the data in the question, the result of the subquery is:

```
id  rid  cnt
 1   2    2
 2   3    2
 1   3    2
```

So, all of these would use the `id < rid` to select the row.  If you had one more row, say `4, 1`.  It would look like:

```
lid gid  cnt
 1   2    2
 2   3    2
 1   3    2
 1   4    1
```

In this case, the first three would take the row with `id < rid`.  But the new row would also be selected because the `cnt` is 1.

If you had duplicates in the table *and* a primary key, there would be a slight variation on the query that would do the same thing.

Comment: This is great, If it's not much of a hassle for you, Can you explain how it works? I mean the second query.